Calculate 3d point on the plane out of 2d point
I have 2d image where 3d plane is displayed. I have 2d coordinate detected on that image, and now I want to check what 3d point on the plane this 2d coordinate corresponds to.
My problem is - calculated 3d position is very inaccurate. Here is my function I ended up using
+ (cv::Point3f)reconstructPoint:(cv::Point2f)point
                          rvecs:(const double *)rvecs_ptr // rvecs corresponds to rotation vector of the plane, was calculated using solvePnP
                           rmtx:(const double *)rmtx_ptr  // rmtx is based on rvecs
                          tvecs:(const double *)tvecs_ptr // tvecs is translation vector of the plane
                            mtx:(const double *)mtx_ptr   // camera intrinsic matrix, was calculated by calibrateCamera
                           dist:(const double *)dist_ptr  // dist coefficients are not used for now...
{
    
    const cv::Mat intrinsic_mtx(3, 3, CV_64F, const_cast<double*>(mtx_ptr));
    const cv::Mat rmtx(3, 3, CV_64F, const_cast<double*>(rmtx_ptr));
    const cv::Mat dist(5, 1, CV_64F, const_cast<double*>(dist_ptr));
    const cv::Vec3d tvecs(tvecs_ptr[0], tvecs_ptr[1], tvecs_ptr[2]);
    
    cv::Mat tvec_mat = (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 1) << tvecs[0], tvecs[1], tvecs[2]);
    
    cv::Mat r1r2t;
    cv::hconcat(rmtx.col(0), rmtx.col(1), r1r2t);
    cv::hconcat(r1r2t, tvec_mat, r1r2t);
    
    cv::Mat H = intrinsic_mtx * r1r2t;
    
    cv::Mat point2D_h = (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 1) << point.x, point.y, 1.0);
    
    cv::Mat projection = H * point2D_h;
    
    double X_world = projection.at<double>(0, 0) / projection.at<double>(2, 0);
    double Y_world = projection.at<double>(1, 0) / projection.at<double>(2, 0);
    double Z_world = 0.0;
    
    return cv::Point3f(X_world, Y_world, Z_world);
}

As you can see, I am putting Z coordinate to 0, and my logic is - I am detecting a point on the plane and according to my logic plane is laid at the neutral Z position==0. So if I detect a 3d point on the plane, it's Z coordinate must be 0 at all times. (Please let me know if my reasoning here is correct).
Here is the output where I tried multiple different points just to see what will be the output:
2d 852.50 632.00  // input 2d point
expected 548.00 548.00 0.00 // What I expect to get (3d points is in physical coordinates)
calculated 2719.51 363.97 0.00 // This is what I reconstructed
5:
2d 1384.00 648.00
expected 960.00 548.00 0.00
calculated 3672.22 411.94 0.00
6:
2d 512.00 484.00
expected 137.00 1188.00 0.00
calculated 2345.80 345.16 0.00
7:
2d 862.00 498.00
expected 548.00 1188.00 0.00
calculated 3192.18 387.77 0.00

What I observe:

The function is incredibly numb in detecting Y coordinate (which actually matters a great deal to me), and incredibly jumpy in detecting X coordinate
X coordinate has an impact on reconstring Y coordinate (for some reason)

Please help me locate where I made mistakes in my approach. Thank you!

[mre] please... and tag your language.
